# request.getParameter returns dirty string

Tags: javascript, request

I have a site which is made by a **CMS**. When the site is visited as normal and a user search on the site with the **URL:**

> https://test.se/test.html?language=sv&SubjectArea=Ekonomi&identity=programSV,coursesSV,lifeLongLearningCoursesSV&showbutton=false

The **JS** code:

```
let test = requester.getParameter("identity") 
console.log(test)
// programSV,coursesSV,lifeLongLearningCoursesSV
```

returns **programSV,coursesSV,lifeLongLearningCoursesSV** as expected.

But when I visit the site at the exact same URL but I come from an external page **JS** code above returns this instead: **programSV%2CcoursesSV%2ClifeLongLearningCoursesSV**

Any suggestions on what could be wrong and how this could be fixed?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [URL search params](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) for consistency - it will decode the URL for you regardless of encoded entities

Alternatively use [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

```js
const url1 = new URL(`https://test.se/test.html?language=sv&SubjectArea=Ekonomi&identity=programSV,coursesSV,lifeLongLearningCoursesSV&showbutton=false`)

const url2 = new URL(`https://test.se/test.html?language=sv&SubjectArea=Ekonomi&identity=programSV%2CcoursesSV%2ClifeLongLearningCoursesSV&showbutton=false`)

console.log(url1.searchParams.get("identity"))

console.log(url2.searchParams.get("identity"))

// alternative

console.log(decodeURIComponent(`programSV%2CcoursesSV%2ClifeLongLearningCoursesSV`))
```

NOTE: decodeURI does nothing for your commas:

```
decodeURI(requester.getParameter("identity"))
```

returns `programSV%2CcoursesSV%2ClifeLongLearningCoursesSV`

however [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) does work:

```
decodeURIComponent(requester.getParameter("identity"))
```

returns `programSV,coursesSV,lifeLongLearningCoursesSV`

Answer (score 0):

the commas are being encoded, you have to use decodeURIComponent. Like this: decodeURIComponent(requester.getParameter("identity")). See link for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Comment: it works, i just tried it with a encoded url string from a url from my work.

Comment: your right, for some reason it needs decodeURIComponent instead of decodeURI. Dont know why my test string worked but that particular string does not. I updated my answer